# Adding Admob to libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx, admob

```
    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    View gameView = initializeForView(new MainGame(), config);

    layout.addView(gameView);


    adView = new AdView(this);

    adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            System.out.println("LOAD");
        }
    });
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-xxx-xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx");

    AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder();
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );
    layout.addView(adView, adParams);
    adView.loadAd(builder.build());

    setContentView(layout);
```

Nothing is shown, no ad, why, 
I added also in build.gradle (Project:projectN)
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:$admobVersion"

Using ubuntu 16.04, android-studio

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java- libgdx build.gradle is not the same for AdMob](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43301569/java-libgdx-build-gradle-is-not-the-same-for-admob)

Comment: For debuging add Test device by  `builder.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR);`

Comment: Check out my question and provided code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41791159/my-admob-banner-is-not-showing

Comment: without firebase, i have no layout also since i was doing by tutorial of codingschool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add AdMob Ads without Firebase :

1. Put these lines inside `build.gradle` of android module.

   ```
   dependencies {

       compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.4'
   }
   ```
2. Add permission in `AndoidManifest.xml` file

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
   ```

   Inside `<application` tag add `Activity` if want to use Interstitial Ads

   ```
   <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
              android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

   <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
             android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
             android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
   ```
3. AndroidLauncher class.

   ```
   public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {

   private static final String adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
   private AdView adView;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();

       RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
       RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
       layout.setLayoutParams(params);

       View gameView=initializeForView(new MyGdxGame(), config);

       RelativeLayout.LayoutParams gameViewParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
       gameViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
       gameViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

       gameView.setLayoutParams(gameViewParams);
       layout.addView(gameView);

       adView = new AdView(this);
       adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
       adView.setAdUnitId(adUnitId);

       AdRequest.Builder adRequestBuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();
       adRequestBuilder.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR);
       adView.loadAd(adRequestBuilder.build());

       RelativeLayout.LayoutParams topParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
       topParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP,RelativeLayout.TRUE);
       topParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
       layout.addView(adView, topParams);
       adView.setBackgroundColor(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT);

       setContentView(layout);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
       adView.resume();
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPause() {
       super.onPause();
       adView.pause();
   }

   @Override
   protected void onDestroy() {
       super.onDestroy();
       adView.destroy();
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: please if you got time, take a look at my question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48499700/2494799