# How can I implement AdMob Ads in a LibGDX Android project?

Tags: java, android, git, libgdx, admob

I found this Flappy Bird GIT project: https://github.com/barodapride/flappy-tutorial-barodapride
How can I implement the BannerAd in this?
There is no layout file.
And how can I implement the InterstitialAd?
If I try to write

```
public InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
```

Then it says "cannot resolve symbol InterstitialAd"

I know how to do this in a normal Android Studio project, but this is the first time I'm working with libGDX and this is so complicated...

Comment: The question as it is right now is too broad. Follow this tutorial to add admob into your libgdx games: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Admob-in-libgdx

Comment: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44014374/adding-admob-to-libgdx/44030876#44030876), how you integrate AdMob banner Ad inside your LibGDX project.

Now I answer `InterstitialAd` integration after Integration of banner Ad.

```
private static final String AD_UNIT_ID_INTERSTITIAL = "ca-app-pub-XXXXX/XXXXX";

private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...
    ...

    interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID_INTERSTITIAL);
    interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
          @Override
          public void onAdLoaded() {}

          @Override
          public void onAdClosed() {
             loadIntersitialAd();
          }
    });

    loadIntersitialAd();
}


private void loadIntersitialAd(){

    AdRequest interstitialRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    interstitialAd.loadAd(interstitialRequest);
}

@Override 
public void showOrLoadInterstitial() {

     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()) 
                     interstitialAd.show();                         
                else 
                     loadIntersitialAd();           
            }
      });
}
```

Need an interface to call `showOrLoadInterstitial` from core module so I created `IActivityRequestHandler` inside core module and implement this interface to `AndroidLauncher` of android module.

```
public interface IActivityRequestHandler {

     void showOrLoadInterstitial();
}
```

**EDIT**

You can't call non-static method, `showOrLoadInterstitial()` with class/interface name, need an object of `IActivityRequestHandler` implemented class so create a parameterized constructor of `MyGdxGame` and pass reference from android module.

```
 public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements IActivityRequestHandler  {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       View gameView=initializeForView(new MyGdxGame(this));
       ....
       ....
   }
```

Capture reference of `IActivityRequestHandler` inside `MyGdxGame` Game class

```
public class MyGdxGame extends Game {

   Public IActivityRequestHandler requestHandler;

   public MyGdxGame(IActivityRequestHandler requestHandler){
       this.requestHandler=requestHandler;
   }

   ...
}
```

Now you've object reference, can called `requestHandler.showOrLoadInterstitial()`

Comment: Hey, nice answer :) I will accept it if you tell me what code I have to write to display it.

For example in an onClickListener. I tried it with this code:
`IActivityRequestHandler.showOrLoadInterstitial();`
But this says: _Non-static method 'showOrLoadInterstitial()' cannot be referenced from a static context_

Comment: `showOrLoadInterstitial` is non-static method, you can't call non-static method with class name, need to call with `IActivityRequestHandler` implemented class's object

Comment: Hey, I really dont get it. This is my project on GitHub: https://github.com/Penta-Games/flappy-tutorial-barodapride-master/ I want to display the add at GameplayScreen.java in the "run()" method. You will find the run() method in the renderPlaying() method. How can I do this? I successfully displayed with your help the Interstitial Ad in a new LibGDX project with only one Java file in the "Core" folder. But this project contains more than 10 java files in the "Core" folder. Please tell me how I can display the Interstitial ad in the "run()" method. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: @FischGesicht sorry for my late reply, I integrated Interstitial Ad in your project and created a [pull request](https://github.com/Penta-Games/flappy-tutorial-barodapride-master/pull/1) for the same, merge it. After merging you'll able to get Interstitial Ad each time when game finish. I also updated version of `gradle`, `gradle android plugin`, `sdk version`, `build tools`, `google play service`...