# Unable to see the both banner and interstitial ads in libgdx framework?

Tags: libgdx, ads

This one was the original code without comments

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration;
import com.gamestudio24.martianrun.MartianRun;
import com.gamestudio24.martianrun.utils.Constants;
import com.gamestudio24.martianrun.utils.GameEventListener;
import com.gamestudio24.martianrun.utils.GameManager;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics;
import com.google.android.gms.games.Games;
import com.google.games.basegameutils.GameHelper;

public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements GameHelper.GameHelperListener,
        GameEventListener {

    private static String SAVED_LEADERBOARD_REQUESTED = "SAVED_LEADERBOARD_REQUESTED";
    private static String SAVED_ACHIEVEMENTS_REQUESTED = "SAVED_ACHIEVEMENTS_REQUESTED";

    private GameHelper gameHelper;

    private AdView mAdView;
    private boolean mLeaderboardRequested;
    private boolean mAchievementsRequested;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create the layout
        RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().clearFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();

        // Game view
        View gameView = initializeForView(new MartianRun(this), config);
        layout.addView(gameView);


        mAdView = createAdView();
        mAdView.loadAd(createAdRequest());

        layout.addView(mAdView, getAdParams());

        setContentView(layout);

        gameHelper = new GameHelper(this, GameHelper.CLIENT_GAMES);
        gameHelper.setup(this);
        gameHelper.setMaxAutoSignInAttempts(0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        gameHelper.onStart(this);
        GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStart(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        gameHelper.onStop();
        GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStop(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        gameHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putBoolean(SAVED_LEADERBOARD_REQUESTED, mLeaderboardRequested);
        outState.putBoolean(SAVED_ACHIEVEMENTS_REQUESTED, mAchievementsRequested);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        mLeaderboardRequested = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(SAVED_LEADERBOARD_REQUESTED, false);
        mAchievementsRequested = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(SAVED_ACHIEVEMENTS_REQUESTED, false);
    }

    private AdRequest createAdRequest() {
        return new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .addTestDevice("461B8D3A7843CE98FD0EBD0917030589")
                .build();

    }

    private AdView createAdView() {
        AdView adView = new AdView(this);

        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId(getAdMobUnitId());

        return adView;
    }

    private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams getAdParams() {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);

        return adParams;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSignInFailed() {
        // handle sign-in failure (e.g. show Sign In button)
        mLeaderboardRequested = false;
        mAchievementsRequested = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSignInSucceeded() {
        // handle sign-in success
        if (GameManager.getInstance().hasSavedMaxScore()) {
            GameManager.getInstance().submitSavedMaxScore();
        }

        if (mLeaderboardRequested) {
            displayLeaderboard();
            mLeaderboardRequested = false;
        }

        if (mAchievementsRequested) {
            displayAchievements();
            mAchievementsRequested = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void displayAd() {
        mAdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void hideAd() {
        mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void submitScore(int score) {
        if (gameHelper.isSignedIn()) {
            Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(gameHelper.getApiClient(),
                    getString(R.string.leaderboard_high_scores), score);
        } else {
            GameManager.getInstance().saveScore(score);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void displayLeaderboard() {
        if (gameHelper.isSignedIn()) {
            startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(gameHelper.getApiClient(),
                    getString(R.string.leaderboard_high_scores)), 24);
        } else {
            gameHelper.beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
            mLeaderboardRequested = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void displayAchievements() {
        if (gameHelper.isSignedIn()) {
            startActivityForResult(
                    Games.Achievements.getAchievementsIntent(gameHelper.getApiClient()), 25);
        } else {
            gameHelper.beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
            mAchievementsRequested = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void share() {
        String url = String.format(" ",
                BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
        String message = String.format(Constants.SHARE_MESSAGE_PREFIX, url);
        Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("text/plain");
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, Constants.SHARE_TITLE));
    }

    @Override
    public void unlockAchievement(String id) {
        if (gameHelper.isSignedIn()) {
            Games.Achievements.unlock(gameHelper.getApiClient(), id);
            GameManager.getInstance().setAchievementUnlocked(id);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void incrementAchievement(String id, int steps) {
        if (gameHelper.isSignedIn()) {
            Games.Achievements.increment(gameHelper.getApiClient(), id, steps);
            GameManager.getInstance().incrementAchievementCount(id, steps);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getGettingStartedAchievementId() {
        return getString(R.string.achievement_getting_started);
    }

    @Override
    public String getLikeARoverAchievementId() {
        return getString(R.string.achievement_like_a_rover);
    }

    @Override
    public String getSpiritAchievementId() {
        return getString(R.string.achievement_spirit);
    }

    @Override
    public String getCuriosityAchievementId() {
        return getString(R.string.achievement_curiosity);
    }

    @Override
    public String get5kClubAchievementId() {
        return getString(R.string.achievement_5k_club);
    }

    @Override
    public String get10kClubAchievementId() {
        return getString(R.string.achievement_10k_club);
    }

    @Override
    public String get25kClubAchievementId() {
        return getString(R.string.achievement_25k_club);
    }

    @Override
    public String get50kClubAchievementId() {
        return getString(R.string.achievement_50k_club);
    }

    @Override
    public String get10JumpStreetAchievementId() {
        return getString(R.string.achievement_10_jump_street);
    }

    @Override
    public String get100JumpStreetAchievementId() {
        return getString(R.string.achievement_100_jump_street);
    }

    @Override
    public String get500JumpStreetAchievementId() {
        return getString(R.string.achievement_500_jump_street);
    }

    private String getAdMobUnitId() {
        return getString(R.string.ad_unit_id);
    }
```

This errors occurs when to generate the ads on libgdx game

07-04 11:57:44.181 8773-8773/com.gamestudio24.cityescape.android D/DynamitePackage: Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdManagerCreatorImpl
    07-04 11:57:44.301 8773-8773/com.gamestudio24.cityescape.android I/Ads: Starting ad request.
    07-04 11:57:44.301 8773-8773/com.gamestudio24.cityescape.android I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("461B8D3A7843CE98FD0EBD0917030589") to get test ads on this device.
    07-04 11:57:47.971 8773-8773/com.gamestudio24.cityescape.android I/Ads: Ad finished loading.

```
            import android.content.Intent;
            import android.os.Bundle;
            import android.view.View;
            import android.view.Window;
            import android.view.WindowManager;
            import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
            import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;
            import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration;
            import com.gamestudio24.martianrun.MartianRun;
            import com.gamestudio24.martianrun.utils.Constants;
            import com.gamestudio24.martianrun.utils.GameEventListener;
            import com.gamestudio24.martianrun.utils.GameManager;
            import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
            import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
            import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
            import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
            import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
            import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
            import com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics;
            import com.google.android.gms.games.Games;
            import com.google.games.basegameutils.GameHelper;

            public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements GameHelper.GameHelperListener,
                    GameEventListener {

                private static String SAVED_LEADERBOARD_REQUESTED = "SAVED_LEADERBOARD_REQUESTED";
                private static String SAVED_ACHIEVEMENTS_REQUESTED = "SAVED_ACHIEVEMENTS_REQUESTED";

                private GameHelper gameHelper;
                private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

                private AdView mAdView;
                private boolean mLeaderboardRequested;
                private boolean mAchievementsRequested;

                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                    // Create the layout
                    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
                    MobileAds.initialize(this,"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");


                    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
                    getWindow().clearFlags(
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

                    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();

                    // Game view
                    View gameView = initializeForView(new MartianRun(this), config);
                    layout.addView(gameView);


                    mAdView = createAdView();
                   // mAdView.loadAd(createAdRequest());

                    layout.addView(mAdView, getAdParams());

                    setContentView(layout);

                    gameHelper = new GameHelper(this, GameHelper.CLIENT_GAMES);
                    gameHelper.setup(this);
                    gameHelper.setMaxAutoSignInAttempts(0);
                }

                @Override
                protected void onStart() {
                    super.onStart();
                    gameHelper.onStart(this);
                    GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStart(this);
                }


                @Override
                protected void onStop() {
                    super.onStop();
                    gameHelper.onStop();
                    GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStop(this);
                }

                @Override
                protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                    gameHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                }

                @Override
                protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
                    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
                    outState.putBoolean(SAVED_LEADERBOARD_REQUESTED, mLeaderboardRequested);
                    outState.putBoolean(SAVED_ACHIEVEMENTS_REQUESTED, mAchievementsRequested);
                }

                @Override
                protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
                    mLeaderboardRequested = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(SAVED_LEADERBOARD_REQUESTED, false);
                    mAchievementsRequested = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(SAVED_ACHIEVEMENTS_REQUESTED, false);
                }

            //        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            //                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            //                .build();



        // I want to show here banner and interstitial ads but its not show what to do for that because i declare banner ad unit id in string.xml and interestitial ad unit id in this android launcher
                private AdView createAdView() {
                    AdView adView = new AdView(this);
                    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
                    adView.setAdUnitId(getAdMobUnitId());
                    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
                    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
                    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
                    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAdClosed() {
                            super.onAdClosed();
                        }
                    });


                    return adView;
                }

                private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams getAdParams() {
                    AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder();
                    builder.addTestDevice(" ");
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);

                    return adParams;
                }

                @Override
                public void onSignInFailed() {
                    // handle sign-in failure (e.g. show Sign In button)
                    mLeaderboardRequested = false;
                    mAchievementsRequested = false;
                }

                @Override
                public void onSignInSucceeded() {
                    // handle sign-in success
                    if (GameManager.getInstance().hasSavedMaxScore()) {
                        GameManager.getInstance().submitSavedMaxScore();
                    }

                    if (mLeaderboardRequested) {
                        displayLeaderboard();
                        mLeaderboardRequested = false;
                    }

                    if (mAchievementsRequested) {
                        displayAchievements();
                        mAchievementsRequested = false;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void displayAd() {
                    mAdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                @Override
                public void hideAd() {
                    mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void submitScore(int score) {
                    if (gameHelper.isSignedIn()) {
                        Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(gameHelper.getApiClient(),
                                getString(R.string.leaderboard_high_scores), score);
                    } else {
                        GameManager.getInstance().saveScore(score);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void displayLeaderboard() {
                    if (gameHelper.isSignedIn()) {
                        startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(gameHelper.getApiClient(),
                                getString(R.string.leaderboard_high_scores)), 24);
                    } else {
                        gameHelper.beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
                        mLeaderboardRequested = true;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void displayAchievements() {
                    if (gameHelper.isSignedIn()) {
                        startActivityForResult(
                                Games.Achievements.getAchievementsIntent(gameHelper.getApiClient()), 25);
                    } else {
                        gameHelper.beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
                        mAchievementsRequested = true;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void share() {
                    String url = String.format(" ",
                            BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
                    String message = String.format(Constants.SHARE_MESSAGE_PREFIX, url);
                    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    share.setType("text/plain");
                    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, Constants.SHARE_TITLE));
                }

                @Override
                public void unlockAchievement(String id) {
                    if (gameHelper.isSignedIn()) {
                        Games.Achievements.unlock(gameHelper.getApiClient(), id);
                        GameManager.getInstance().setAchievementUnlocked(id);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void incrementAchievement(String id, int steps) {
                    if (gameHelper.isSignedIn()) {
                        Games.Achievements.increment(gameHelper.getApiClient(), id, steps);
                        GameManager.getInstance().incrementAchievementCount(id, steps);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public String getGettingStartedAchievementId() {
                    return getString(R.string.achievement_getting_started);
                }

                @Override
                public String getLikeARoverAchievementId() {
                    return getString(R.string.achievement_like_a_rover);
                }

                @Override
                public String getSpiritAchievementId() {
                    return getString(R.string.achievement_spirit);
                }

                @Override
                public String getCuriosityAchievementId() {
                    return getString(R.string.achievement_curiosity);
                }

                @Override
                public String get5kClubAchievementId() {
                    return getString(R.string.achievement_5k_club);
                }

                @Override
                public String get10kClubAchievementId() {
                    return getString(R.string.achievement_10k_club);
                }

                @Override
                public String get25kClubAchievementId() {
                    return getString(R.string.achievement_25k_club);
                }

                @Override
                public String get50kClubAchievementId() {
                    return getString(R.string.achievement_50k_club);
                }

                @Override
                public String get10JumpStreetAchievementId() {
                    return getString(R.string.achievement_10_jump_street);
                }

                @Override
                public String get100JumpStreetAchievementId() {
                    return getString(R.string.achievement_100_jump_street);
                }

                @Override
                public String get500JumpStreetAchievementId() {
                    return getString(R.string.achievement_500_jump_street);
                }

                private String getAdMobUnitId() {

                    return getString(R.string.ad_unit_id); // Declare the banner ad unit id its in string.xml
                }

            }
```

Comment: where is `createAdRequest()` method ?, It's better to delete all commented lines.

Comment: @Abhishek Aryan all commented lines are old code and i implemented new code with the help of google https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner!!

Comment: could you be please remove old/unwanted code by edit, that help me to understand what's going wrong

Comment: @AbhishekAryan I updated the original code now!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- By `createAdView()` method you're not loading ad on `adView` only you're calling `loadAd()` method on `mInterstitialAd` , that may be one of the reason that you not getting banner Ad. Also you should call `addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)` on Request Builder, if your App is in testing mode.
- Loading InterstitialAd is not enough, after loading you need to call `show()` method on InterstitialAd.

I've already answered, how you should integrate AdMob in LibGDX :

1. Banner Ad Integration : [Adding Admob to libgdx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44014374/adding-admob-to-libgdx/44030876#44030876)
2. Interstitial Ad Integration  : [How can I implement AdMob Ads in a LibGDX Android project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44485172/how-can-i-implement-admob-ads-in-a-libgdx-android-project/44486362#44486362)