# How to add interstitial ad on Libgdx game?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, admob

How do you add admob interstitial ad on your Libgdx Android game? There are tutorials on how to add ad banners, but can't find anything specific for Libgdx regarding interstitial ad.

Answer (score 3):

Integration of AdMob Ads in LibGDX projects

- Banner Ad Integration : [Adding Admob to libgdx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44014374/adding-admob-to-libgdx/44030876#44030876)
- Interstitial Ad Integration : [How can I implement AdMob Ads in a LibGDX Android project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44485172/how-can-i-implement-admob-ads-in-a-libgdx-android-project/44486362#44486362)