# Libgdx -> AdMob my banner is visible after clicked

Tags: android, libgdx

I configured admob in my application, but the problem is when i start a game. I just not see a banner, just when i click it then add is opening and when i back to game i see the banner. I don't know whats wrong. My application have a black background

Here is my code:

```
adView = new AdView(this);
AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
cfg.useAccelerometer = true;
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
View gameView = initializeForView(new SkippyFlowersGame(this), cfg);
relativeLayout.addView(gameView);
adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            Log.i(TAG, "Ad Loaded...");
        }
    });
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
adView.setAdUnitId("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder();
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
relativeLayout.addView(adView, adParams);
adView.loadAd(builder.build());
setContentView(relativeLayout);
```

Comment: Where you declare your ad request in onCreate() or onResume() ?

Comment: Well Im not declared

Comment: Ahh sorry in OnCreate

Comment: protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

Comment: Okey try to put it into the onResume(). So whenever onResume() call you got the new ad. Make sure you do not have margin or padding because of it it block the ad and not showing.

Comment: As I see in your code you are creating a Relativelayout programmatically and then you used your adview and everything. For my opinion why don't you create the xml file and declare the adview inside that xml and just call here in activity it is very easy to handle then programmatically create the layout.

Comment: Its a libGDX game, and here is not any layouts

Comment: Opps sorry.. I don't see that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're calling `pause()`, `resume()` and `destroy()` methods of  `AdView` by overriding methods of `Activity` in this way :

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    if (adView != null) {
        adView.pause();
    }
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (adView != null) {
        adView.resume();
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (adView != null) {
        adView.destroy();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Moreover still having problem, take a look of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44014374/adding-admob-to-libgdx/44030876#44030876). It may be helpful.