# How to get ADmob banner adds to show in Libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx, admob

I am trying to get a banner ad to show at the bottom of my game in libgdx. The game compiles and runs fine but no ads are showing. How can i check if ads are being setup properly and what can i change in my code to display ads.

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {

    private AdView adView;

    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();

        RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        layout.setLayoutParams(params);

        View gameView=initializeForView(new BuckyRun(), config);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams gameViewParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        gameViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        gameViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

        gameView.setLayoutParams(gameViewParams);
        layout.addView(gameView);

        adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId("secret");

        AdRequest.Builder adRequestBuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();
        adView.loadAd(adRequestBuilder.build());

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams topParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        topParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP,RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        topParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        layout.addView(adView, topParams);
        adView.setBackgroundColor(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT);

        setContentView(layout);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        adView.resume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        adView.pause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        adView.destroy();
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding Admob to libgdx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44014374/adding-admob-to-libgdx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Ad Unit ID  will take time 12 hours to come live on google.

Upto that time test with App ID to initialize the SDK: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713.

Refer [MobileAds](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start)