# LibGdx with AdMob but not using Scene2D, how do I use the View?

Tags: android, libgdx, admob

I have an existing LibGdx game that I'd like to try to
add AdMob ads to, but it doesn't use Scene2D, stage and actor,
it's like LibGdx's JuperJumper, it only deals with Viewports
and the Camera.

Every LibGdx AdMob example I've seen is using Scene2D
or is some weird Android application really with some LibGdx in it.

I've seen all the code examples that return an Android View,
but I don't know how to "connect" my LibGdx game to it,
or be able to use that View.

My code has a 'PlayScreen' that implements Screen, and 'GameTest' that extends Game
and the usual Android Activity that extends AndroidApplication,
but I haven't seen anything on how to get those to work with the Android View.

I'm just interested in using it for Android, not on the desktop or anywhere else.
I'm doing it on Windows.

Does anybody know of an example project that is close to that?

Or what bit of code would I need to be able to use the View?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you see: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Admob-in-libgdx

Comment: Yes I read that.  The problem with that is that it isn't "integrating" a real LibGdx game application.  It's like trying to take SuperJumper, which doesn't use Scene2D, and add ads to it.  Nowhere does it describe how to use the Android View in an app like that.

Comment: If you are expecting to put AdMob ads inside of your game content, I doubt that will happen as from what I recall the AdView is a WebView implementation with JavaScript ads using [IAB MRAID API](https://www.iab.com/guidelines/mraid/). Even if it isn't a webview, AdMob wants as much control for metrics/fraud prevention and talks directly to Android framework. Generally those ads are placed in static areas like menus, or exist outside(or perhaps on top) of the game view. See similar questions like [Adding Admob to libgdx](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44014374/295004)

Comment: I know you have to have that Android layer with the two Views, one for your game and the other for the ads, but I can't find anything on how to use the View your game would use.  Every example I've seen is all using Scene2D, stage and actors, my LibGdx game doesn't use that.

Comment: The game uses Viewport and Camera.  So far I haven't seen anything on how they can relate to an Android View.

Comment: Have you at least tried the recommended integration code to see what happens? To my (limited) understanding once `initializeForView` is correctly setup, your LibGdx should just run.

Comment: Yeah, I'll give that a shot.  I'm in the middle of a different issue, but once I have some time I'll try to put something together.  Thanks!

Comment: Hey Morrison, I got pretty far with adding the needed AdMob stuff into my AndroidApplication, and I've looked at, and added, all the Google information on setting up the ads, but now I keep getting:  "com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException".  You are right, I think setContentView() just does some magical thing.

Comment: Hey Morrison, Thanks for getting me motivated to just try it.  It took a lot of fiddling, but I finally was able to get test ads going!

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question with any details or if something wasn't explained clearly by the [related linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44014374/295004) or existing documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I posted a similar question and someone helped me figure out
how to get things to finally work!

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69107001/how-to-get-the-admob-and-libgdx-game-views-to-work-on-android
```