# How to get the AdMob and LibGdx game Views to work on Android

Tags: android, libgdx, admob

I ended up using most of the AdMob Banner example code from:

https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/master/java/admob/BannerExample

Along with parts of other example source of "extends AndroidApplication"
Android launcher.

It builds, and from the Listener onAdLoaded() message, it appears that the ads
are getting loaded, but my game screen always takes up the entire screen.

I've tried to reduce the size of the game's Viewport, but have not had any luck.

The game's code does not use Scene2D, so it doesn't use Stage or Actor,
only the Viewport and Camera.

This is for LibGdx Android only, using Windows for development.

What can I do to get the two Views to properly appear and show the game screen
and the ad?

I've tried to use all kinds of different variations of code,
and the latest play-services-ads version,
but the end result is the same.

Thanks!!

Here is the code:

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.6.0'
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.jps.gamenew" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <!-- Sample AdMob App ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"/>

        <activity
            android:name="G_GameNewActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenSize" >
            
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
    package com.jps.gamenew;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import android.util.Log;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.lang.Object;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.RequestConfiguration;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.InitializationStatus;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.OnInitializationCompleteListener;

/*
import com.google.android.gms.ads.admanager.AdManagerAdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.admanager.AdManagerAdView;
/**/

public class G_GameNewActivity extends AndroidApplication
{
    static final String TAG = "G_GameNewActivity";
   private static final String BANNER_AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111";
  protected AdView adView;
  protected View gameView;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    cfg.useAccelerometer = false;
    cfg.useCompass = false;

    // Do the stuff that initialize() would do for you
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params =
        new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    layout.setLayoutParams(params);

    setContentView(layout);

    // Initialize the Mobile Ads SDK.
    MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus)
        {
        }
    });

//I/Ads     ( 7493): Use RequestConfiguration.Builder().setTestDeviceIds(Arrays.asList("723B283FA24BF57D2A1BA9A7C34BDF6C"))
//to get test ads on this device.

    // Set your test devices. Check your logcat output for the hashed device ID to
    // get test ads on a physical device. e.g.
    // "Use RequestConfiguration.Builder().setTestDeviceIds(Arrays.asList("ABCDEF012345"))
    // to get test ads on this device."
    MobileAds.setRequestConfiguration(
        new RequestConfiguration.Builder().setTestDeviceIds(Arrays.asList("723B283FA24BF57D2A1BA9A7C34BDF6C"))
            .build());

    AdView adView = createAdView();
    layout.addView(adView);

    adView.setAdListener(new AdListener()
    {
        @ Override
        public void onAdOpened()
        {
          Log.d(TAG, "\nonAdOpened()");
        }
        
        @ Override
        public void onAdLoaded()
        {
          Log.d(TAG, "\nonAdLoaded()");
        }
        
    });
 
    View gameView = createGameView(cfg);
    layout.addView(gameView);
    
    
    // Create an ad request.
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    // Start loading the ad in the background.
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

  }

  private AdView createAdView()
  {
      Log.d(TAG, "\n\ncreateAdView()");
    adView = new AdView(this);

    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    //adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
    adView.setAdUnitId(BANNER_AD_UNIT_ID);      // "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
    //adView.setAdUnitId("/6499/example/banner");
    
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    adView.setLayoutParams(params);
    adView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    return adView;
  }

  private View createGameView(AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg)
  {
    gameView = initializeForView(new GameTest(), cfg);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, adView.getId());
    gameView.setLayoutParams(params);
    
    return gameView;
  }

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (adView != null)
        adView.resume();
  }

  @Override
  public void onPause() {
    if (adView != null)
        adView.pause();
    super.onPause();
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    if (adView != null)
        adView.destroy();
    super.onDestroy();
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Instead of manually creating a layout, I would create an xml layout that has the adView and a FrameLayout representing the game in it. Then you can make sure it's laid out the way you like in the editor. Then in your activity, call `initializeForView` and add the returned view to the FrameLayout. There's nothing you need to do in the core module. The viewport will be sized to fit whatever android View is hosting the game.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  I looked back at the example link I made at the top and it had a layout XML and I tried that, but with the TextView part commented out, plus some other tweaks, and the ad showed up fine! But I have no idea how to construct the part for my game's View in it and how to use '[View] = initializeForView(new GameTest(), cfg);' with it.  If you, or someone, could help me out with that, that would be cool!  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an XML layout like this:

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/game_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ad_view"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/ad_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:adSize="BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then in your activity, initialize for view, and add the view to the FrameLayout container. I also removed the way you were using your `createGameView` method because it was juggling member variables, local variables and return values very confusingly. Also, you were forgetting to assign your AdView instance to the member variable. You assigned it to a local variable instead, so the lifecycle events aren't getting passed to it.

```java
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    cfg.useAccelerometer = false;
    cfg.useCompass = false;

    // Do the stuff that initialize() would do for you
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.my_layout)

    // Initialize the Mobile Ads SDK.
    MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus)
        {
        }
    });

//I/Ads     ( 7493): Use RequestConfiguration.Builder().setTestDeviceIds(Arrays.asList("723B283FA24BF57D2A1BA9A7C34BDF6C"))
//to get test ads on this device.

    // Set your test devices. Check your logcat output for the hashed device ID to
    // get test ads on a physical device. e.g.
    // "Use RequestConfiguration.Builder().setTestDeviceIds(Arrays.asList("ABCDEF012345"))
    // to get test ads on this device."
    MobileAds.setRequestConfiguration(
        new RequestConfiguration.Builder().setTestDeviceIds(Arrays.asList("723B283FA24BF57D2A1BA9A7C34BDF6C"))
            .build());

    adView = findViewById(R.id.ad_view)

    adView.setAdListener(new AdListener()
    {
        @ Override
        public void onAdOpened()
        {
          Log.d(TAG, "\nonAdOpened()");
        }
        
        @ Override
        public void onAdLoaded()
        {
          Log.d(TAG, "\nonAdLoaded()");
        }
        
    });
 
    gameView = initializeForView(new GameTest(), cfg);
    findViewById<FrameLayout>(R.id.game_container).addView(gameView);
    
    // Create an ad request.
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    // Start loading the ad in the background.
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!  I just saw how you can add a View to the layout, but I'll try your code!  Thanks!!!

Comment: Oops, I forget to update the part where you get the FrameLayout reference. Just updated it.

Comment: I had to change your "findViewById<FrameLayout>(R.id.game_container).addView(gameView);"  to:   FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.game_container);
frameLayout.addView(gameView);     But it WORKED!!!  Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Ah okay, I’d forgotten the correct syntax in Java for that.